# Disk defragging with unmovable files

Tags: windows, hard-drive, defragment, mydefrag

I moved my hard disk from my laptop to my desktop in order to defrag it. I am using [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com) to defrag the disk. I was hoping that since the OS used was my desktop's and not my laptop's, the system files wont be unmovable.

So far, I was able to defrag my page file which was in 80k over fragments. However, the `hiberfil.sys` remains unmovable even though it wasnt in use. Several files that is prefixed with `$` was also unmovable. How can I release these unmovable files from active usage?

Comment: Just disable hibernation to solve the fragmentation issue on that file, not that it being fragmented is a performance problem

Comment: @Ramhound I dont mind that particular file being fragmented. However it is fragmented about 50k fragments and being unmovable, the make contiguous free space impossible. The also end up fragmenting some rather large files as theres no contiguous free space available for that size.

Answer (score 1):

hiberfil.sys will be removed by Windows if you do the following:
1. Turn off hibernation in control panel.
2. Open shell as administrator and enter: `powercfg.exe -h off`

Rem: In Windows Explorer->Tools->Folder Options->View Tab 
Uncheck "Hide Protected Operating System Files" in order to confirm that hiberfil.sys is really gone. It is located in C:. After that you can re-rerun your defrag program.

[image: Screenshot of Explorer->Tools->Folder Options]

[image: Screenshot of sane settings]

Answer (score 0):

you can clear up some of the $ files, with fsutil.
fsutil usn deletejournal /d DISKLETTER:
This will stop proper journaling temporarily and delete a bunch a $jrnl file items that half the time I do not know why they are there. The journaling is one of the file systems safety features for recovering when things are not written https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system . it is also used other odd ways like storing the index data temporarily. . . then leaving it there?

use
fsutil usn queryjournal DISKLETTER:
to just view

---

Another item , that only exists on the operating system partition, that usually does not represent a lot of space, but can be cleaned up too is this resources stuff, I forget even what my research was for it.
fsutil resource setautoreset true DISKLETTER:

Use
fsutil resource info DISKLETTER:
just to get a view.

I have been running these 2 cleanups prior to defrag for years now with zero problems, but my system is also minimised some, and I do not actually use indexing.  Because a person would want to have a backup anyway prior to defragging a disk (because it moves all data around) Having a backup prior is still needed.

Replace DISKLETTER: with the actual disk D:  it is in obnoxious caps so it is understood that it is not finished without changing that.